# How to configure ubuntu to use bluetooth U2F key?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a pair of Google Titan security keys and want to configure ubuntu 18.04 to accept them for login.  The instructions for a Yubikey [here](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000011356-ubuntu-linux-login-guide-u2f) work well for USB.  I haven't found a recipe yet to use the bluetooth connection to the Titan key on ubuntu. Any suggestions on how to do that would be welcome.

Comment: Same problem here. Works fine on USB. New BT BLE receiver 'sees' it, but can't pair either using the GUI nor bluetoothctl. BTW, I have the original Feitian branded one, not the Google OEM

Comment: I am able to pair mine in Ubuntu with bluetoothctl but I don't know what the next step is to making the system see it as a u2f key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same desire, found that the BLE key is only intended for use with Android or iOS devices over Bluetooth at this time. The key will work when hard connected.

More information at https://support.google.com/titansecuritykey/answer/9115487?hl=en.